# Some doubts about SQL Injection examples, how exactly works?

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection, injection, owasp

I am a software developer starting studying application security and I have the following doubt related SQL injection.

I am following a video course and there are these two examples:

1. I have an insecure SQL query like this:

   ```
   txtSql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = " + txtUserId
   ```

   If the passed value of `txtUserId` is something like `99 OR 1 = 1`, I will obtain a query like this

   ```
   SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = 99 OR 1 = 1
   ```

   which will return me the entire list of record contained in the `Users` table because `1 = 1` is always true and the `OR` concatenation will return true so it is like this query:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM Users WHERE TRUE
   ```

   returning me the entire list of records. Is this reasoning correct?
2. Then I have this second more sophisticated example:

   There is a user login form (username and password). Behind this form there is this insecure query implementation:

   ```
   sql = 'SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE Name = "' + uName + '" AND Pass = "' + uPass + '"'
   ```

   If the user inserts the following data into the login form:

   ```
   uName = " OR ""="
   uPass = " OR ""="
   ```

   The result query will be:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name = "" OR ""="" AND Pass = "" OR ""=""
   ```

   So it is selecting records where

   - The `Name` field is empty ("") or equal to `"="` (and this condition should be always false because it is pretty strange to have an empty user name or an username like "=").
   - The `Pass` field is empty ("") or equal to `"="` (and this condition should be always false because it is pretty strange to have an empty password or a password like "=").

   So we have a conditional like:

   ```
   WHERE FALSE AND FALSE
   ```

   And here my doubt: `FALSE AND FALSE = FALSE`

Why does it say that this query returns me the entire list of records of the user table?

If I understood the logic correctly, the second query should translated to something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE FALSE AND FALSE
```

What is wrong in my reasoning? What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've misread the injection, specifically this part:

`""=""`

This isn't checking if the `Name` is an equal sign, but rather if an empty string is equal to an empty string.  It's effectively the same thing as `1=1` (and they could have used `1=1` just as well here), and is therefore the equivalent of `TRUE`.  So this clause:

`Name = "" OR ""=""`

Is the same as `Name="" OR 1=1` as well as `Name="" OR TRUE`

It's easy to misread something like that.  I'm sure that's all you need, since you otherwise understand these concepts clearly!  Just to be a pedant though, the query basically boils down to:

`WHERE Name="" OR TRUE AND Pass="" OR TRUE`

What happens next might depend on the exact order of precedence, but it will probably be fine.  Another trick you could use would be to end the username with a backslash remove `Pass` from the query all together (although this may not work in all flavors of SQL).  Imagine injecting `User=\` and `Pass= OR 1=1 --` (ends in a comment).  You'll end up with this query:

`SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE Name="\" AND Pass = " OR 1=1 --"`

Because of the backslash it will be searching for a `Name` of `" AND Pass =` (which won't match anything), but then the `OR 1=1` will make it match everything.  The ending comment gets rid of the last double quote which would otherwise cause a syntax error.  This form gives you a bit more control over the query by effectively nuking the search on the `Pass` column and therefore ditching all the `AND`/`OR` clauses.  For instance, you could search for an actual ID by changing your `Pass` condition to `OR ID=10` (presuming there is an `ID` column).

Comment: Ahhh so let me check if I well understood the point: doing Name = "" OR ""="" I am checking if the PARAMETER passed for the Name field (that is empty string) is "" (an empty string) or "%" (an other way to specify the empty string). So the check is on the passed parameter. I could also do something like this to obtain my injection: SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name = "foo" OR "foo" AND Pass = "" OR ""=""

Comment: @AndreaNobili Not quite.`Name="foo" OR "foo"` wouldn't be valid syntax.  The two clauses are separate:`Name=""` and the `""=""` are completely unrelated.  `""=""` is perfectly valid SQL on its own, for instance you could have a query that simply says: `WHERE ""=""`.  The key is that the "column name" doesn't have to be an actual column name but can be anything, including a literal empty string.  So `""=""` asks, "Is an empty string equal to an empty string?" which is always true.  This is effectively the same thing as `1=1` which is also always true.

Comment: In other words, you could exchange `""=""` for `1=1` and the query would operate exactly the same way, since both clauses just evaluate to `True`.  You would even be able to see that in the query plan.

Comment: nitpick: escaping with backslashes in a string constant is not standard sql and may not work, depending on the database being used and how it's configured

Comment: @Eevee Indeed.  Different SQL systems have plenty of play, so it is worth mentioning, but I've added a comment about how it depends on the actual database in use.

Comment: @ConorMancone `Name="foo" OR "foo"` valid syntax but invalid semantics as `OR` expects two boolean values as its arguments. Yet, it's valid syntax.

Comment: @bash0r Good call.  Comments are editable though, so...